# Auto sort script on google sheets onChange trigger

Tags: javascript, sorting

Can anyone help me please, it's regarding auto sort script for google sheets? I'm not familiar with script actually, but what I'm trying to do is to auto sort the dates entered on column A on my table range. I found a generic script below which I tried on my google sheets and it actually works on manual edit on the same sheet. 
However, the values on my table range are results of my (Index,Match) formula from another sheet so whenever a new value is entered from another sheet it will not automatically get sorted.

Here's the sample script which I tried on my google sheets:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:J61"; // What to sort.
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me to modify this script, please...

Here's the link to sample google sheet which I'm trying to work on:

https://docs.google.com/a/alarmpromotions.org/spreadsheets/d/1IHPwNpAklt_5R6OyxTHMxMbXKkT4WsPBk20saUPbxgw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What errors does it throw?

Comment: Auto sort will only work if I manually edit the column on the same sheet (sheet1), however the values on sheet 1 are results of the formula with basis from sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this onEdit with the auxiliary function to update first sheet when this is triggered for the second sheet.

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:J61"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true});

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    if(ss.getSheets()[1] == sheet ){
       sortFirstSheet();
    }
  }
}


function sortFirstSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:J61");
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true});
}
```

Take a look at these [APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Hi Rajeev - oh thank you so much for your assistance I copied it now and it does work, however, seems like I have to click on run to have it work. Is it right that it should be onEdit trigger?

Comment: Yes, it should be onEdit trigger for the second sheet which would automatically call both the functions. Hope you understood the code as well!!

Comment: Hello again, Is there a way to modify this script again that would auto sort if my sheet 2 or my reference sheet is the result of an "importrange" formula?

Comment: My sheet 1 (where the auto sort should be) is the result of an index/match formula, then the basis of that is from sheet 2(which is also the result of an importrange formula) so basically, the manual edits is on the another workbook. Can anyone guide me to modify this script, please. Thank you very much....